# Adding multiple custom HTTP Header to API Client in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, httpclient

I want to send multiple http request headers to a 3rd party API, but somehow it seems my request is not a valid one. Below is the headers which I have to send:

```bash
  -H 'REQUEST_ID: 5' \
  -H 'ACTION_ID: 5' \
  -H 'username: 5' \
  -H 'password: 5'
```

In my C# code the client header set is like this:

```cs
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", "5");
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username", "5");
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ACTION_ID", "5");
ApiHelper.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("REQUEST_ID", "5");
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it valid to add multiple pairs to `DefaultRequestHeaders` List?
2. Am I doing it right?